# How do I link a City field so that when I click a city, all the associated names to that city populate the dropdown menu in another provided field?

Tags: relationship, filemaker

On FileMaker Pro,

I made a field for list of `Cities` into a dropdown menu.

I also made another field in the form of a dropdown menu for `Names` associated to the `Cities` in the dropdown menu field above it.

When I pick a `City`, all the `Names` associated to that selected `City` should populate the drop down menu in the `Names` field.

How can I implements this on FileMaker Pro?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a conditional value list. You'll find complete instructions [here](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5833/~/creating-conditional-value-lists), but basically you'll set up a relationship between the cities and the names based on the `City` and set up a value list based on the `Name` field with the option to "Include only related values starting from" and specify the relationship between the two (step 12 in the instructions).